# Como exportar un datagrid en un pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, wpf, datagrid

como pudiera exportar un datagrid de mi aplicación de wpf a un pdf, estoy haciendo uso de la librería Itexsharp, es un datagrid de 6 columnas. He visto varias soluciones y la mayoría usan datgridview.

Comment: Y cual seria el problema? hay un set de datos y lo mas probable es que eso se exporta no?

Comment: El problema es que esta es la primera vez que trabajo en wpf, y con la libreria itexsharp, y no tengo mucha idea la verdad de como hacerlo, me imagino que tenga que recorrer el datagrid, pero poco más.

Comment: wpf es solo la capa de presentacion... habria que ver que estas viendo, pero un datagrid tambien se puede recorrer...

Comment: mi aplicacion se encarga de crear un pdf a partir de una plantilla que yo ya tengo diseñada, la informacion del pdf la entra el usuario mediante la aplicacion, la cual tiene varios textbox, y varios datagrid para almacenar la información de las tablas, ya la información de los textbox me salen en el pdf una vez que presiono el botón de crear pdf, solo me faltan los datagrid

Comment: y el codigo de tu intento de bajar la grilla al pdf? no intentaste recorrerla ni nada?

Comment: es ahí exactamente donde tengo mi duda,no se como exportar el datagrid a mi pdf programáticamente

Answer (score 0):

```
Finalmente lo resolvì de la siguiente manera:
  

    var tab = new PdfPTable(6) { WidthPercentage = 100 };
      var list = DataGrid.Items.OfType<T>().ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    tab.AddCell(list[i].los atributos que contenga la lista);
                    tab.AddCell(list[i].Entity);
                    tab.AddCell(list[i].Activity);
                    tab.AddCell(list[i].Start);
                    tab.AddCell(list[i].End);
                    tab.AddCell(list[i].High);
                  
                }
                doc.Add(tab);
```